# How to execute a method Once during Runtime on c#

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, runtime

Is there a possibility to prevent method execution more than once during Run-time of an Instance without using an external Attribute ?

I hope i was clear !
Bests

Comment: what do you mean with 'external attribute'? Pls show some code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: like if we use bool IsExecuted = false; ,than on first time we switch IsExecuted = true ,and than we test if(IsExecuted) throw an Exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: How would that help exactly? How would a static constructor test when the method is run or prevent method subsequent method execution?

Comment: The method can be enclosed in a static ctor of the class & "The static constructor for a non-generic class executes at most once in a given application domain" copied verbatim from ECMA C# spec - http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3A_17.11_Static_constructors

Comment: it works by 

// Static constructor is called at most one time, before any
// instance constructor is invoked or member is accessed.
and  a value can be set that is changed when the method is called. next time the method tries to execute first it checks the value.

Comment: Love it. OP specifies "prevent method execution more than once during Run-time of an Instance" and then marks an answer talking about static constructor as the answer. You need to be a mindreader sometimes.

Comment: I didn't ask for these powers ;)

Comment: A static constructor would limit to one execution *per class*. The OP asked for one execution *per instance*.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class TestClass
{
static private bool _isExecutedFirst = false;

public void MethodABC()
{
if(!_isExecutedFirst)
_isExecutedFirst = true;
else
throw Exception("Method executed before");
/////your code

} 
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: This is one run per class - the OP asked for one run per instance.

Answer (score 0):

sure, with a flag to indicate whether a method on an instance has been run.

```
public class RunOnceMethod
{
  private bool haveIRunMyMethod = false

  public void ICanOnlyRunOnce()
  {
    if(haveIRunMyMethod)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("ICanOnlyRunOnce can only run once");

    // do something interesting

    this.haveIRunMyMethod = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 
you can use like this

```
void method(args)
{
    static int a;
    if(a != 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    // body of method and 
    a++;
}
```

reason being this static a will not be copied to activation records of the function calls and all will share only one a.

I hope this resolve your question.

Comment: You can't declare a variable as static within a method. Also the question asked for once per instance.

Comment: duh... i thought he's asking for C++ one

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to prevent method execution without storing some kind of 'state' saying the method has already been executed.

One way of doing this is a "guard" / check at start:

```
private bool AExecuted = false;
public void A()
{
    if (AExecuted)
       return;
    else
       AExecuted = true;

    /* Your code */
}
```

Comment: shouldn't AExecuted be static ?

Comment: @AB Kolan - no? He wants per instance guards.